# Modified variable variables

Tags: php, variables

```
$m = 'this_is_m';
$this_is_m = 'this_is_m_not_full :(';
$this_is_m_full = 'this_is_m_FULL!! :D';

print ${$m};
```

(Hi first :P) Outputs:

```
this_is_m_not full :(
```

Any idea how to output `this_is_m_FULL!! :D` **using** `$m`??

What I've already tried:

```
print $"{$m}_full";
print $'{$m}_full';
print $'$m_full';
print ${$m}_full';
```

None worked... Thanks in advance,,

Comment: Have you considered just using an array?

Comment: if you have to use variable variables you have some major design flaw...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution would be:

```
print ${$m . '_full'};
```

But that feels very hackish.

Answer (score 2):

To get your desired output, you need to do the following:

```
print ${$m . "_full"};
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
print ${$m.'_full'};
```

This is because the string inside the braces will get evaluated first, becoming

```
print ${'this_is_m' . '_full'}  
  ->  print ${'this_is_m_full'}  
  ->  print $this_is_m_full
```

Take a look at [this manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) if you want more information on this.